# Flattening JSON objects using Python

Tags: python

I have a json object

```
sample_json ={
"workspaces": [
    {
        "wsid": "1",
        "wsname": "firstworkspace",
        "report":[{"reportname":"r1ws1"},{"reportname":"r2ws1"},{"reportname":"r1ws1"}]
    },
    {
        "wsid": "2",
        "wsname": "secondworkspace",
        "report":[{"reportname":"r1ws2"},{"reportname":"r2ws2"},{"reportname":"r1ws2"}]
    }
]}
```

I want to flatten/normalize the json so that it looks like this :

[image]

I can flatten each level using the pandas function "json_normalize"
e.g Level 1

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.json_normalize(sample_json, record_path=['workspaces'])
df1
```

[image]

e.g Level 2

```
import pandas as pd
df_api = pd.json_normalize(sample_json, record_path=['workspaces','report'])
df_api
```

[image]

I have read quiet a few articles such as [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-pandas-json-normalize-you-should-know-for-flattening-json-13eae1dfb7dd) but I am struggling to understand how to include information from the two levels (workspaces and reports) in a single dataframe. Any advice or help would be appreciated. Copy to sample data in a google colab notebook [is here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iNArvLD-8RH7EEH0KFPgktBFrc7cmkTE?usp=sharing)

Comment: this has nothing to do with JSON. There is no JSON involved, there is a *dictioanry*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [`jertl`](https://jertl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be used for this.

```py
In [1]: import jertl

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: sample_json = ... #removed for brevity

In [4]: pattern = '''
   ...: {
   ...: "workspaces": [*_,
   ...:     {
   ...:         "wsid":   wsid,
   ...:         "wsname": wsname,
   ...:         "report": [*_, {"reportname": reportname}, *_]
   ...:     },
   ...:     *_]
   ...: }
   ...: '''

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(match_.bindings for match_ in jertl.match_all(pattern, sample_json))

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
  wsid           wsname reportname
0    1   firstworkspace      r1ws1
1    1   firstworkspace      r2ws1
2    1   firstworkspace      r1ws1
3    2  secondworkspace      r1ws2
4    2  secondworkspace      r2ws2
5    2  secondworkspace      r1ws2
```

`pattern` defines the structure to look for. It is intentionally JSON like.
`wsid`, `wsname` and `reportname` are variables.
The `*_`s are splatted anonymous variables which match any number of list items.

##### Shameless self promotion alert. I am the author of jertl.

Answer (score 0):

So, just normalize this yourself.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"wsid": ws['wsid'], "wsname": ws['wsname'], **rep}
        for ws in sample_json["workspaces"] for rep in ws['report']
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you explain the mechanics of what is going on here?